# Postman giving different response

Tags: ios, swift, post, postman

I am a beginner in swift iOS and I am doing login module of an application in iOS but I am stuck at one thing I have login api but when I am checking response in postman when I am sending parameters as "raw" than it is showing user logged in but when I am sending the same parameters as "form-data" than it is showing wrong id and password....can anyone tell me how to send parameters as "raw" so that I can get correct response?? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Please provide a screenshot your postman request.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this method if you are using Alamofire library for API call.

```
func request(_ method: HTTPMethod
    , _ URLString: String
    , parameters: [String : AnyObject]? = [:]
    , headers: [String : String]? = [:]
    , onView: UIView?, vc: UIViewController, completion:@escaping (Any?) -> Void
    , failure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

    Alamofire.request(URLString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in


            switch response.result {
            case .success:                 
                completion(response.result.value!)
            case .failure(let error):

                failure(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Also remember you need to pass Application/JSON header while calling this method.

```
["Content-Type": "application/json"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/

Check if your raw is using the correct format type as specified below.

[image]